# SQL : How to tranaslate to sql?

Tags: sql

How to translate to sql ?

`if  $ORD_SENT is not (null | "") &  $ORD_AMENDED is not (null | "") then display “Amended & Sent”`

`else if  $ORD_SENT is not (null | "") &  $ORD_AMENDED is (null | "") then display “Sent”`

Comment: For starters, what does (null | "") mean in the code above? And are you asking how to translate TO sql? You wrote "in".

Comment: I asking how to translate to sql

Comment: Which SQL dbms are you using?

Comment: yes, i'm using SQL dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH(ORD_SENT) > 0 AND LENGTH(ORD_AMENDED) > 0 THEN 'Amended & Sent'
     WHEN LENGTH(ORD_SENT) > 0 AND (ORD_AMENDED IS NULL OR LENGTH(ORD_AMENDED) = 0) THEN 'Sent'
     ELSE null END
```